# Operate DOM after loaded when page prerendered on server side with Angular universal?

Tags: angular, dom, angular-universal

I'm writing some animations with DOM operations for Angular2 components. However, when page is prerendered on server side and sent to the browser, there is no binded event listeners. Even when I added DOM codes in the wrapper of `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {}`, I still can't get those event listeners, because there is no `<script></script>` tags in the HTML. So my question is that if there is a way to add event listeners when page is prerendered on the server side.

```js
foo(): void {
    // DOM codes here
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        this.foo();
    }
}
```